# Create Optional Parameter conditionally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two parameters called “Loan” and “Tier”. Both are single select drop down list and I am fetching values for these parameters from sql queries. Tier parameter is dependent on Loan.

Below are sql queries for fetching Loan and Tier respectively:

SELECT LOAN FROM LOAN

SELECT TIER FROM LOAN WHERE LOAN=@Loan

There are some loans for which there is no data in TIER table, so for these loans  and blank value get displayed for Tier drop down. Also, for those loan which has some tiers, , , , etc are getting displayed for Tier drop down.

Now, when I select a loan (for which there is no tier), I have to explicitly select blank value from the Tier drop down, otherwise it gives me a pop up message saying that “Please Enter value for Tier”.

In this scenario, I want that user should not need to explicitly select blank value, user should be able to view the report if he/she does not select value for tier (Pop up message should not get appear).

The second thing, If user select a loan (for which there are some tiers available), then user has to select Tier from the Tier drop down. Otherwise, validation pop up message (“Please Enter value for Tier”) should get appear.

Basically, I want to create optional parameter conditionally. If Tier has some value (for selected loan), then Tier parameter should be mandatory, otherwise it should be optional.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot control parameter workflow to the extent you want.

I would add a DISTINCT clause to the query for the Tier parameter.

Then I would set the default value for the Tier parameter to the blank value.  This can be tricky - you may need to substitute another value e.g. `ISNULL ( TIER , 'Unspecified' )`, then set Default value to `Unspecified`.